# Trying to fix my ubuntu installation and I am getting this EFI error

Tags: grub2, uefi, live-usb, grub-efi

Anyone know what this error is about?

[image]

Comment: The only time I've seen that is when I've omitted (manual partitioning/something-else) to allocate/select the `/boot/efi` partition; but your screengrab shows an install option I don't normally use sorry; I usually go back a step & select the partition I omitted to select.  I don't see that error often enough to advise sorry

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this recently myself.

You need to go back a step and choose "do something else" to get to the partition listing, find the efi partition and right-click, select 'change'.

I forget the exact wording, but in the dialogue that pops up there will be a "use as" option select, choose efi, and accept changes. You should also make sure / and swap partitions are set correctly ("use as" / or swap respectively).

Then continue with the installation.

Worked for me, seems the installer can miss the partition for some reason.